# how to rename a file while uploading PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, file, upload

I am using following code to upload file , every thing is working fine , i just want to upload file with new name  that should be current time of uploading , Actually i want to upload file with name as upload time

```
<?php


$statusMsg = '';

// File upload path
$targetDir = "../uploads/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    // Allow certain file formats
    $book_title=$_POST['book_title'];
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
            // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT into books (book_title,book_author,book_image,book_url) VALUES ('','','".$fileName."', '.')");
            if($insert){
                $statusMsg = "The file ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully.";
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
            } 
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, & PDF files are allowed to upload.';
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}

// Display status message
echo $statusMsg;

?>
```

Comment: So change the `filename` that you use. Instead of using the filename from the users file, create one of your own

Comment: So `$fileName = 'Make_something_up.extn';`

Comment: can you plz code it for me , i am new to PHP

Comment: What do you want your new filenames to look like?

Comment: there should be carrent date before file name. plz do changes in my code and re paste it , i have tried many sites but  unable to do fruitful changes

Comment: _“can you plz code it for me , i am new to PHP”_ - please stop using that as an excuse here on this site. We are not here to make stuff _for you_, we are here to support you with problems with code you have written, that you can not solve yourself - _after_ you made a reasonable effort first. Going “please write this for me” _immediately_ after you have been told what needs to be done, is not making an effort.

Comment: dear ! I am not asking to create some thing for me , I was searching for about 3  hours , but found no solution. Actually i was not getting the point where to change file name , at which line , so asked for this but as @RiggsFolly has posted , it took me no time to understand , and i have told that it worked for me, Thanks alot to him again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding current date in to the filename received from the user

```
$fileName = date('Y-m-d_') . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

In case they add more than one file in a day you could also add the time as well

```
$fileName = date('Y-m-d_His_') . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `$_FILES['file']['name']` is the actual name of file user uploads, suppose user uploads the file **'demoImage.jpeg'** from the explorer then it is the actual name assigns to `$fileName` in your code, just modify this line of code as given below:

Change this

```
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

to

```
$fileName = Date('His') . $fileType;
```

You can change the Date function's parameter to generate specific date/time for your file name.